# Location of .apk file

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I recently built an Android application using Eclipse (Galileo) on my PC/Xp. I'm a noob to Android development and it took me 2 months to build my app while reading/experimenting with all the Java and other programming ups/downs. The project runs fine on Eclipse. I now want to sign the application (currently reading on how to do this) in preparation to releasing it to the Android Market. At this point, I am stumped. The "signing your application" talks about signing the .apk file with your private key. My question is: where is the .apk file located on my PC/Eclipse files. I know where the src, res, manifest, and R.java files are located because I've been using them for the past 2 months. Where is the .apk file located? Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17342273/2100372

Answer (score 20):

In Eclipse the default location for a compiled *.apk file is in the `bin` directory under the project workspace.

For example, my Eclipse workspace is under `c:\Users\crsierra\workspace` and my Eclipse Project is named `HelloWorld`.  Therefore the `HelloWorld.apk` file will be located under `c:\Users\crsierra\workspace\HelloWorld\bin\HelloWorld.apk`

Comment: This is what I've been looking for: a default location of my `.apk` files in eclipse projects...finally! I had no idea where to put it!

Comment: not always true. I had to export as in Zoombie's answer.

Answer (score 12):

In eclipse right click on your project and in that menu select **Android tools->Export signed Application package** .

And In that appearing dialog follow the instructions.

Comment: I downvoted this because I came here looking for a *specific directory location* to put my generated `.apk` files. @crsierra's answer has that.

Comment: but that is *unsigned apk* ... if u want to install in device u need *signed apk* for generating signed apk this is the easiest way @droogans

Comment: I upvoted this because I came here looking for a _specific directory location_ to put my generated .apk files. But they weren't there. @Ganapathy had the right answer for me (although I did choose "unsigned" apk)

Answer (score 3):

You can export signed and unsigned .apk file using eclipse, as well as can generate private key too just use **Project folder -- > right click --> Android tools**

Answer (score 2):

> If you already running your project on emulator,you just close that emulator.And goes to

```
Project->clean
Project->BuildProject.
```

> And then run your project in emulator and then check it out

```
bin/res/your.apk file
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically in the `bin` folder.

Comment: I usually find it in the bin folder, but for a few of my projects, it wasn't to be found. I had to use Android Tools -> Export Unsigned APK. Any reason as to why that happened?

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple, Go to :

**Workspace -> YourApp folder** & in that folder type in the search bar(top-right)  for your `YourApp.apk` !