# Can't find apk file

Tags: android, eclipse

I made my first android app and it works on the emulator.

But now I want to test it on my phone and I can't find the apk file.
Do I have to make it and how do I do that?

Comment: Have you built it first?

Comment: I have answered the same question to generate apk [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017210/eclipse-is-not-generating-apk-file-for-any-app-developed-in-it/17018093#17018093

Comment: @Mohit Verma suggest correct way use that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

followin way to find .apk build file...

1. open your project
2. open "bin" folder
3. get your project's build (.apk) file.

You show in Image where it is.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just check the bin folder of your Project source code folder.

Comment: @zoran404 that is not the correct way!

Comment: it's in the bin folder, I didn't noticed it. thanks, it works on my phone

Comment: and why is it not the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse right click on your project and in that menu select Android tools->Export signed Application package .

And In that appearing dialog follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can  find last build apk file in this directory : /projectFolder/bin/yourapp.apk

here yourapp.apk is just an example

**OR**

you can do something following

> 1.right-click the project in the Package Explorer
>
> 2.select Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package.
>
> 3.Then specify the file location for the signed .apk.

Answer (score 0):

check Bin folder in project structure
**OR** attach phone with debugger on & run on phone
**OR** Right click on project & andorid tools -> export sign package

Comment: inappropriate method!